# Unique maximum element of Scala list

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I wish to do a max function using apache flink with Scala that returns the maximum element, if it is unique, and -1 otherwise. For better understanding there is an example below:

`2` is the return of the function for `list[1, 2, 1]`.

`-1` is the return of the function for `list[3, 3, 1]` due to the max result it will be three, but is not an unique appearance in the list of this max value.

I thougth that i could do by putting all elements on a seq, but this won't work after with flink, so i tried to do using reduce, but i got no success :/

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Use Flink API to fold the list. Start with a tuple of (0, 0). the first is the max number so far and the second is the number of times you found that number.

When you find a number x which is greater than _1 of the tuple you creates a tuple (x, 0). If you find a number which is less than x then ignore. if you find a number which is equal to x then increment the _2 of the tuple.

At the end of the fold you will have a tuple which is (x, y) where x is the maximum number and y is the number of times you found that number.

How a simple if condition will help you return the x or a -1.

Edit: Flink has deprecated the fold function. Use the AggregateFunction for traversing the list.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
 val x: List[Int] = ???
 val grouped: Map[Int, List[Int]] = x.groupBy(identity)
 val uniqueElements:List[Int] = grouped.filter( _._2.size == 1 ).map(_._1).toList
 val maxVal = if(uniqueElements.isEmpty ) -1 else uniqueElements.max
```

Comment: he is doing it in flink. not regular scala collections.

Comment: ohh okay. My solution doesn't help then :(